# Calling completion block once objects are written in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using `Realm` and I love it so far but now I'm trying to find a way to know when objects are written in Realm.
Let's say I remove objects from Realm :

```
func deleteObjects<T: Object>(objects: Results<T>)
{
     let realm = Realm()
     try! realm.write {
         realm.delete(objects)
     }
}
```

Is there some existing method that would allow me to know when these objects are deleted from the database ? Something like :

```
func deleteObjects<T: Object>(objects: Results<T>)
{
     let realm = Realm()
     try! realm.write {
         realm.delete(objects, completion {
            print("Objects deleted")
         })
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to know when the `delete` has completed? It's a synchronous operation, so the objects have been deleted when the call returns. The deletion becomes visible to other threads after the write transaction is committed (i.e., the block you pass to `write` completes) and their Realms refresh to pick up the changes (either via an explicit call to `Realm.refresh`, or via auto-refresh happening on the next runloop iteration).

Comment: All right ! I didn't know that, really cool. Thanks @bdash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Realm.delete(_:)` is a synchronous operation, so the objects have been deleted when the call returns. The deletion becomes visible to other threads after the write transaction is committed (i.e., the block you pass to write completes) and their Realms refresh to pick up the changes (either via an explicit call to `Realm.refresh`, or via auto-refresh happening on the next runloop iteration).

Comment: `Realm.delete(_:)` is not a synchronous operation! I have intermittent app crashes because of this. I call the delete all objects command. Then I call the write new objects command. And when the available objects are subsequently called, a failure occurs when accessing them: **Fatal Exception**: _RLMException
Object has been deleted or invalidated_.
Similarly `Realm.write(_:)` is not a synchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

[Full documentation here for Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes).

This is the relevant section.

```
// Add to the Realm inside a transaction
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(author)
}
```

And using your example.

```
func deleteObjects<T: Object>(objects: Results<T>)
{
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write({ 
            realm.delete(<#T##Object#>)
        })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here is another example, using a closure passed in to the function.

```
func deleteObject(object: Object, completionClosure: () -> ()) {
    if let realm = object.realm {
        do {
            try realm.write({
                realm.delete(object)
                completionClosure()
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the catch block called when there is an error to catch only ?